# How do you change the inner circle color of a LineGraph in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to make charts in Android app.

I need to make circle blue with just white border of that circle, like this on the image below.

[image]

This is my code:

```
        LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals,"DataSet");
        set1.setFillAlpha(65);
        set1.setFillColor(Color.RED);
        set1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE);
        set1.setLineWidth(2f);
        set1.setCircleSize(5f);
        set1.setDrawValues(false);
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the image above, it looks like you need to use `setCircleColorHole(int color)`.

According to the docs:

> Sets the color of the inner circle of the line-circles

So this may be what you are after:

```
 LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals,"DataSet");
        set1.setFillAlpha(65);
        set1.setFillColor(Color.RED);
        set1.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        set1.setCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
        set1.setCircleColorHole(Color.BLUE)
        set1.setLineWidth(2f);
        set1.setCircleSize(5f);
        set1.setDrawValues(false);
```

I haven't used this library but you may also need to add `setDrawCircleHole(true)` should that not work on its own.

Comment: That is it, it works very well without setDrawCircleHole(true). Do you know how to make chart background like on the first image?

Comment: Afraid not, never used the library! If you have other questions, I suggest reading the docs for the library and if that doesnt help, making a new question here.

Comment: @Zookey could you find the solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I could not find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If this is done within a fragment

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
       trendsDataSet.setCircleColor(getActivity().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
       trendsDataSet.setCircleHoleColor(getActivity().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
          }
```